# Why is my jQuery click handler not handling signs of life?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, event-handling

I have a set of checkboxes where I am trying to assign per-item click handlers. The code that generates the checkboxes, inside a loop, is:

```
    if (is_unique)
      {
      entry += '<span class="unique">';
      entry += '<input type="checkbox" title="Mark this event as complete." class="hide-instance" id="hide-instance-' + element.id + '-' + element.regular_expression.replace(/ /g, '-').replace(/\./g, '_') + '">&nbsp;';
      }
```

The code intended to assign the click hander begins:

```
    (function(matches_date, element)
      {
      var identifier = ('hide-instance-' + element.id + '-' +
        element.regular_expression.replace(/ /g, '-').replace(/\./g, '_'));
      console.log("Marking 1: " + identifier);
      console.log("Marking 2: " + element.id);
      console.log("Marking 3: " + matches_date.toDateString());
      console.log("Marking 4: " + jQuery('#' + identifier).length);
      jQuery('#' + identifier).click(function(event)
        {
        console.log("Reached here!");
```

My Chrome log has the "Marking" lines 1-4, the fourth one outputting a 1, and I am seeing what I expect in the generated HTML with one checkbox. However, I never see "Reached here!" in my log output, and the log output does not print anything seriously wrong.

What kind of diagnostics can I give to help solve this problem?

Comment: Try replacing `jQuery('#' + identifier).click(function() {` with [`jQuery(document).on('click','#'+identifier, function() {`](http://api.jquery.com/on) to provide event delegation for dynamically-created elements. Better yet, use the class `.hide-instance` instead of the ID.

Comment: Does the event handler function run before the `is_unique` condition? If so you'll need event delegation.

Comment: delegation doesn't seem to make sense as being the problem, since the 4th mark log shows that at least 1 element with that id does exist. If delegation does fix it, then it's more likely that the problem is duplicated id's.

Comment: I shot myself in the foot. Instead of appending to innerHTML, I was assigning jQuery('#foo').html(jQuery('#foo').html() + new_data). I'm looking to see if the problem's solved when I assign handlers after the div contents have been completed.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is a checkbox use change instead of click event

Comment: Actually..I just wanted it as a suggestion... because I don't get it why the click wont work if the length marking 4 is 1....unless there is any other element with the same id on the page and the generated id's are invalid.So the other element is actually registered with the click.